# Importance of seed and num_runs in the KMeans clustering

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, pyspark, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

New to ML so trying to make sense of the following code. Specifically

1. In `for run in np.arange(1, num_runs+1)`, what is the need for this loop? Why didn't the author use `setMaxIter` method of `KMeans`?
2. What is the importance of seeding in clustering?
3. Why did the author chose to set the seed explicitly rather than using the default one?

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator
    
def optimal_k(df_in,index_col,k_min, k_max,num_runs):
        '''
        Determine optimal number of clusters by using Silhoutte Score Analysis.
        :param df_in: the input dataframe
        :param index_col: the name of the index column
        :param k_min: the train dataset
        :param k_min: the minmum number of the clusters
        :param k_max: the maxmum number of the clusters
        :param num_runs: the number of runs for each fixed clusters
    
        :return k: optimal number of the clusters
        :return silh_lst: Silhouette score
        :return r_table: the running results table
    
        :author: Wenqiang Feng
        :email:  von198@gmail.com.com
        '''
    
        start = time.time()
        silh_lst = []
        k_lst = np.arange(k_min, k_max+1)
    
        r_table = df_in.select(index_col).toPandas()
        r_table = r_table.set_index(index_col)
        centers = pd.DataFrame()
    
        for k in k_lst:
            silh_val = []
            for run in np.arange(1, num_runs+1):
    
                # Trains a k-means model.
                kmeans = KMeans()\
                        .setK(k)\
                        .setSeed(int(np.random.randint(100, size=1)))
                model = kmeans.fit(df_in)
    
                # Make predictions
                predictions = model.transform(df_in)
                r_table['cluster_{k}_{run}'.format(k=k, run=run)]= predictions.select('prediction').toPandas()
    
                # Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score
                evaluator = ClusteringEvaluator()
                silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
                silh_val.append(silhouette)
    
            silh_array=np.asanyarray(silh_val)
            silh_lst.append(silh_array.mean())
    
        elapsed =  time.time() - start
    
        silhouette = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(k_lst,silh_lst)),columns = ['k', 'silhouette'])
    
        print('+------------------------------------------------------------+')
        print("|         The finding optimal k phase took %8.0f s.       |" %(elapsed))
        print('+------------------------------------------------------------+')
    
    
        return k_lst[np.argmax(silh_lst, axis=0)], silhouette , r_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions based on my reading of the material.

1. The reason for this loop is that the author sets a new `seed` for every loop using `int(np.random.randint(100, size=1))`. If the feature variables exhibit patterns that automatically group them into visible clusters, then the starting seed should not have an impact on the final cluster memberships. However, if the data is evenly distributed, then we might end up with different cluster members based on the initial random variable. I believe the author is changing these seeds for each run to test different initial distributions. Using `setMaxIter` would set maximum iterations for the same `seed` (initial distribution).
2. Similar to the above - the seed defines the initial distribution of `k` points around which you're going to cluster. Depending on your underlying data distribution, the clusters can converge in different final distributions.
3. The author has control over the seed, as discussed in points 1 and 2. You can see for what seed your code converges around clusters as desired, and for which you might not get convergence. Also, if you iterate for, say, 100 different seeds and your code still converges into the same final clusters, you can remove the default seed as it likely doesn't matter. Another use is from a more software engineering perspective, setting explicit seed is super important if you want to, for example, write tests for your code and don't want it to randomly fail.